# Sas Intrnet session error message

Tags: session, sas

According to the **SAS documentation**,

it should be simple to start a Sas Intrnet session: simply run the following code in SCL.

```
 init:

    rc=appsrv_session('create');

  return;
```

Well, it doesn't work. When I try to compile this code, I get this **error**:

> **ERROR:** [Line 12]  Function APPSRV_SESSION is not supported or is misspelled.

Any Sas programmer who knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have SAS/Intrnet licensed and installed?  Run `proc setinit;run;` and make sure that you see a line with `---SAS/IntrNet` in your log.  What environment are you running this in?  What SAS version are you using?

Comment: Yes. Sas/Intrnet is installed, license until march 2016. It's running on AIX 64 with Sas version 9.2 (build 1462D)

Comment: Robert, no need to find a solution anymore. I got word from our Sas support that it's technically possible, but we aren't allowed to use it... A real pity. Thanks for your efforts!!!

Answer (score 0):

I close this questions because it has no meaning anymore. My Sas support department forbid the use of sessions.

Anyone who put effort in this: a BIG thanks. (That's you **Robert Penridge**)